# How can I embed an existing podcast into my website?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, web, podcast

I manage a podcast and a website, currently they are separate but I would like to have a way to embed the podcast into the website, I still want to create/update the podcast separate from the website I just want visitors to be able to listen to the podcast on the website without having to open iTunes while still having the ability to choose what episode to play. The best solution I have found is: http://tools.wizzard.tv/ but I do not like it that much. Currently I have to log on and click refresh for it to recognize new episodes.

I want to be able to update the podcast, and just like how iTunes will be updated I want the page on the website to be updated as well. The 'podcast' page will most likely not be like a blog but have a Flash or Java script, maybe HTML5 application that will pull the info from the podcast.xml file to show the episodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions for this problem:

The [first solution](http://www.bigcontact.com/feedplayer.php) shows the podcast in a widget, in which you can tell its hosted outside the site.

The [second solution](http://www.joeworkman.net/rapidweaver/stacks/rss-list/) is a little more native, however to use it you must be making you site in RapidWeaver and this solution costs a wee bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the updated podcasts as they are added to iTunes, use an iFrame. The iFrame should point to your iTunes Preview page. You probably don't want to display the iTunes Preview page top navigation bar and all of the links at the bottom of the iTunes Preview page and there is a way around that.

Place your iFrame inside a div and use some inline styling to get the dimensions you want and trim off the top and bottom using negative margins. Note that the negative margins top and bottom in the iFrame are subtracted from the iFrame height so the actual height is 500px. Should look something like this.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<iframe src="link-to-podcast" scrolling="auto width="100%" frameborder="0"
height="980px" allowtransparency="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
style="margin: -80px 0 -400px 0;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use WordPress for your site, a great option is [PowerPress](http://www.blubrry.com/powerpress/). Also, if you want to keep the podcast off your website but still give listeners an option other than iTunes, check out [Blubrry](http://www.blubrry.com/)